# Seeking a jQuery spiral bound book effect plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins

I am in need of a jQuery plugin which can give me book flip effect with a nice spiral image in between pages, and flip of pages.

By spiral effect I mean:

[image]

I have tried many plugins but none provides a middle image customization and opening and closing book effect, I mean front page and end page.

Has anyone ever encountered some plugin, or some plugin that can be customized to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [turnjs](http://www.turnjs.com/#home). It's without the spiral, but it is simple and nice looking.

Comment: check also BookBlock plugin [tutorial](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/12/11/fullscreen-pageflip-layout/). Hope helps someone.